# CardView showing black (not so good looking) shadows in pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

Cardview on **pre-lollipop** devices show an ugly black gradient when long pressed or click where it would normally show ripple in devices with Lollipop or greater.

[image: cardview ugly pre-lollipop]

Here is my CardView XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/swipe_section_padding"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout ...
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290323/how-to-make-cardview-according-to-material-design-in-android/37290652#37290652 check this works well in pre l

Comment: Try to add this as `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead of `foreground`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding **card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"** attribute,

> useCompatPadding  boolean: true> if CardView should add padding for the
>   shadows on platforms Lollipop and above.

check [cardview:cardUseCompatPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        card_view:contentPadding="0dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView >
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: I haven't got the time yet. I will try this and let you know.